# Comparing two cells for exactness using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering how to compare two cells for an if statement (as a condition)

The cells have letter, numbers, and spaces.

I know of the function exact(-,-) but vba does not have it.

Comment: `If Range("A1").Value2 = Range("A2").Value` - Is there a reason this simple statement will not work?

Comment: that's what I tried at first. but I think usually that's for comparing numbers or words

Comment: is it a built in function?

Comment: @Dean - but if you need an *exact* match comparing `Value2` of one cell to another should work, no? It doesn't matter if the cell has alphanumeric characters within it.

Comment: The "If" should work, if it isn't show us the values for two cells were it isn't working correctly and we can help. You might trim using the "Trim" function in front of each cell, the if won't work if there are spaces at the end of one, but not the other.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan_Sav that works perfect

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use:

```
  StrComp(element1,element2,vbBinaryCompare)
```

Comment: It would be polite if you'd attribute the person who made the suggestion to you in a comment... Just click "edit" below your Answer. And then click the "checkmark" to mark it as the Answer. Even better would be if you tell that person it helped and allow him to write the answer, which you then mark as the Answer so that he gets the "reputation" for his contribution :-)